OAuth consent screen is verified but still 100 user cap showing
I'm hoping to get some clarification on Google Sign-in for my website and app. I've successfully verified my OAuth consent screen, but I'm seeing a "100 user limit" displayed.
Here's the situation:
Google Sign-in Functionality: Users can currently log in with Google without any issues.
No Scopes Requested: I haven't added any scopes in my configuration.
100 User Limit: The OAuth consent screen shows a 100 user limit, which is confusing since I don't have any scopes. However, the OAuth consent screen is verified.
My questions are:
Can unlimited users log in with Google despite the 100 user limit?
Is it safe to ignore the 100 user limit in my case?
Any guidance or insights from the community would be greatly appreciated!
I attached screenshots for reference.
Thanks in advance,
screenshot
Confusion with 100 User Limit after verified account.

I think this same question has been asked a few times.
Does this answer your question:
How to lift the 100 user cap for OAuth to Google API for verified apps
